# The output of the above C Language code is Rs.10.008 but why?

Tags: c

The output of the above C Language code is Rs.10.008 but why ?????

```
#include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
        unsigned i = 10;
        i = printf("Rs.%d.00",i);
        printf("%d",i);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Do you assign `i = printf(...)` on purpose?

Answer (score 2):

This statement:

```
i = printf("Rs.%d.00",i)
```

prints `Rs.10.00` and returns `8` to indicate the number of characters printed.  Notice that you are assigning the return value of printf to `i`.

Hence, the subsequent printf statement:

```
printf("%d",i);
```

Will now print `8` instead of `10`.  The first printf statement didn't specify an end-of-line char (`\n`), so it just concatenates the `8` onto the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has undefined behavior as you use `%d` for printing **unsigned int**. You need to use `%u` for unsigned (int) and `%d` for (signed) int.

If that is fixed we have...

For `printf` the C standard says:

> Returns

> The printf function returns the number of characters transmitted, or a negative value if
> an output or encoding error occurred.

So

```
int i = 10;   // Note unsigned changed to int
i = printf("Rs.%d.00",i);
```

will print "Rs.10.00" and set `i` to 8 because "Rs.10.00" is 8 characters long.

Then

```
printf("%d",i);
```

will print "8" so that the total output is "Rs.10.008"

Answer (score 0):

printf() return the number of characters that are printed, since your code is printing 8 characters so the value assigned to i after executing first printf is 8, and since new line is not added before second printf its printing the value of i in same line resulting in Rs.10.008

first printf is printing the value of i that is 10

```
i=printf("Rs.%d.00",i) // it prints Rs.10.00 and assign the value of i=8
```